# Potential Energy of proton as per Quark Model

Tags: nuclear-physics

In a quark model of elementary particles, a proton is made of
two up quarks [charge (2/3) e] and one down quarks [charges
–(1/3) e]. Assume that they have a triangle configuration with
side length of the order of 10–15 m. If we Calculate electrostatic
potential energy of proton following this concept, it comes out to be zero. What is the physical significance of this answer?

Comment: How did you calculate the electrostatic potential of the proton or the triangle, exactly?

Comment: Its a problem given in a book.